# Keras padding replaces all my values by 0

Tags: python, lstm, padding

In order to adapt a sequence of data I want to use in a univariate LSTM and that have a "multi-step time", The simplest way is to do some padding. 
My initial dataset looks like this, it's a numpyarray:

```
X
[0.295046, 0.325147, 0.361293]
[0.249307,0.444077]
[0.570017,0.525082,0.475404,0.390616]
```

What I've tried so far is:

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
padded_x = pad_sequences(X)
print(padded_x)
```

Instead of adding zeros to "complete" the dataset:

```
X
[0.0, 0.295046, 0.325147, 0.361293]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.249307,0.444077]
[0.570017,0.525082,0.475404,0.390616]
```

It just replaces all the values by 0. I don't know what I am missing...

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `pad_sequences`'s `dtype` argument is set to `'int32'`, thus resulting in the rounding of your float values to 0. You thus need to use `pad_sequences(x, dtype='float32')` (or `'float64'`, as you see fit).

Comment: Maybe use `dtype=x.dtype` for generality?

Comment: @Nour You are welcome! And if I were you I would also take the clever advice from @OllinBoerBohan of using `x.dtype` :-)